# iOS Swift Detecting Image Rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an app which animates a needle on a meter as long as the user is pressing on the screen.  When the finger is lifted I need to know the rotation angle of the needle.  I remove all animations as soon as the finger is lifted but I can't figure how to get the current rotation angle of the  needle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple, this is the full solution:

**Sample Setup:**

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 6) // just to test (it is 30 in degrees and 0.523598775598299 in radians)
```

**Code:**

```
let rad: Double = atan2( Double(imageView.transform.b), Double(imageView.transform.a))
let deg: CGFloat = CGFloat(rad) * (CGFloat(180) / CGFloat.pi )
print(deg) // works, printing 30
```

where `deg = degrees` and `rad = radians`

**Explanation:**
The first line is getting the radians, and the second line is multiplying the radians by the equivalent of a radian in degrees, to get the degrees.

---

**NOTES:**

1. In `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: someValue)`, `someValue` is, in fact, the radians of the angle, it is not measured in degrees. More information about:

   - **[radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)**
   - **[degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle))**
   - **[PI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi)**
2. The value in degrees of the radian `CGFloat.pi` is 180, therefore you can test it for any angle depending on this.

---

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That was perfect!  I really do need to do some study on advanced math.